# How to force horizontal scrollbar with Syncfusion SfDataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, syncfusion

I am hiding/showing columns and adjusting their widths dynamically.  The `SfDataGrid` has trouble catching up, and in some border cases, calculates the width wrongly, and hides the horizontal scrollbars even though part of a column expands beyond the visible part of the `SfDataGrid` or is hidden behind the vertical scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

You can overcome this behavior by customize the style of Scrollviewer and remove the rowspan and columnspan values respectively as mentioned in this [article](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/5908/how-to-show-horizontal-and-vertical-scrollbars-without-overlapping).

You can get the default ScrollViewer style through visual studio designer by right click on the ScrollViewer and navigate through the open context menu to the EditTemplate option. Afterwards just click on the Edit a Copy option.